# How to disable and re-enable menu bar

Tags: javascript, electron

I would like to disable the menu bar (make it grey and unopenable).
How to do that?

I tried the following code but it removes the menu bar instead of disabling it.

```
Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (being Electron v18.1.0) , you can't disable top level menu items.

See Github issue # 8703 [Menu enabled/visible property doesn't affect top-level menu items](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8703#issuecomment-426679882) for more information.